# Запрет определенного пути к папке или файлу в Edit

Tags: delphi

В Edit прописывается путь к файлу или папке: `каталог программы\save`

Как сделать так что бы если в Edit прописывается путь `каталог программы\save` то при нажатию на кнопку - показывалось сообщение - `"Обрабатывать файлы в указанной папке запрещено"`. Папка `save` всегда расположена возле самого exe программы.

Я предполагаю что нужно прописать что то вроде этого или может ошибаюсь ?: `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)`

Как сделать это с словом я уже разобрался:

```
const NoValid = 'save';

if Pos(Edit1.Text, NoValid) <> 0 then
begin
  ShowMessage('Обрабатывать в файлы в указанной папке запрещено');
  Exit;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ради интереса, попробовала сделать вот так и вот мой вариант (если, конечно же, устроит):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s, s1, s2: string;
  p, p2: integer;
begin
  // Строка где ищем
  s := Edit1.Text;
  // Слово 1 по которому ищем (с большой буквы)
  s1 := 'Save';
  // Слово 1 по которому ищем (с маленькой буквы)
  s2 := 'save';
  // Осуществляем поиск в Edit используя функцию Pos
  p := pos(s1, s);
  p2 := pos(s2, s);

  { Проверка: Если в строке (Edit) существует слово - Save (с большой буквы) }
  if p > 0 then // если слово есть
  begin
    // если слово первое
    if ((p = 1) and (s[p + length(s1)] = '\'))
    // или в середине
      or ((s[p - 1] = '\') and ((s[p + length(s1)] = '\')
      // или в конце
      or (p + length(s1) - 1 = length(s))))
    // Тогда очищаем Edit
    then Edit1.clear;
    // И выводим сообщение
    ShowMessage('Обрабатывать в файлы в указанной папке запрещено');
    // Выходим
    Exit
  end;

  { Проверка: Если в строке (Edit) существует слово - Save (с маленькой буквы) }
  if p2 > 0 then // если слово есть
  begin
    // если слово первое
    if ((p2 = 1) and (s[p2 + length(s2)] = '\'))
    // или в середине
      or ((s[p2 - 1] = '\') and ((s[p2 + length(s2)] = '\')
      // или в конце
      or (p2 + length(s2) - 1 = length(s))))
    // Тогда очищаем Edit
    then
      Edit1.clear;
    // И выводим сообщение
    ShowMessage('Обрабатывать в файлы в указанной папке запрещено');
    // Выходим
    Exit
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Вы уже второй раз меня выручаете. Ваш код вполне подходит. Меня устраивает еще и то что он запрещает любые пути с словом Save. Респект ВАМ Татьяна.

Comment: @Денис, меня, в свое время, тоже выручали тут же и сейчас выручают. Кстати, если не хотите прописывать этот код к каждой кнопке (ну если у Вас кнопок много) то пропишите его в Edit и он будет всегда срабатывать как при вставке так и при печати в Edit.

Answer (score 2):

Код с комментариями:

```
// Получаем путь к запрещенной папке, без \ на конце
restrictedPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'save';

// Проверяемый путь приводим к стандартному виду,
// чтобы нам не подсунули ".\save" или "каталог программы\save\..\save\"
testPath := ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExpandFileName(Edit1.Text));

if SysUtils.SameText(testPath, restrictedPath) then
begin
  ShowMessage('Обрабатывать в файлы в указанной папке запрещено');
  Exit;
end;
```

Comment: А переменные restrictedPath,testPath: string; Правильно ?

Comment: Получается если путь вот так : C:\Users\adm\Desktop\save То не срабатывает. А если просто слово в Edit то срабатывает.